# Debug linked modules using WebStorm

Tags: next.js, webstorm, lerna

I'm attempting to debug a Next.js project within a Lerna monorepo using WebStorm. Currently, WebStorm doesn't halt at the source files, although it does stop at breakpoints within the code located in the `node_modules` directory. I suspect that WebStorm is not following the links created by Lerna.

Is there a configuration option available to ignore the node module files and instead focus on the source code?